# Is it proper to allow "double dependency" for classes?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I'm currently in the process of building a new <strike>"framework"</strike> "CMS" for my site - Prior, everything was built using a "procedural" method (Using globals to prevent redundant information, etc). It wasn't really anything to brag about. It's my first time out working with "OOP", so try not to be frightened by my possibly twisted logic.

I seem to have run into something a bit sketchy. Logically (As far as I know) it appears to the best solution, but even so it doesn't seem right.

For instance, say I have the following class:

```
class BindClass {

  public $DATABASE;
  public $USER;
  function __construct($database,$user) {
    $this->DATABASE = $database;
    $this->USER = $user;
  }

}
```

The value `$DATABASE` is an instance of the class `Database`, and the value `$USER` is an instance of the class `User`:

```
$database = new Database(); // Database
$user = new User($database); // User Information
$bind = new BindClass($database,$user);
```

Notice how `User` depends on `Database` (To access user information), and how `BindClass` depends on both `User` and `Database`. Since `User` already includes `Database`, wouldn't that technically be *two* instances of `Database` when all is said & done?

Is that not a proper way to reach my desired conclusion (`BindClass` being able to access the 'properties' of `User` & `Database`), and if so, what's the "right way"? My main concern is that I'm "including" something that already is "connected" to `Database`.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Explain? Did I use improper terminology? The "previous" iteration of the site wasn't much to begin with and not complete.

Comment: + for the OOP part of the question. You are correct that ideally you don't need an overlap in class. And while you didn't explain the purpose of `BindClass`, it almost certainly should not exist.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary `BindClass` was supposed to be something that "held" various dependencies, that way I wouldn't have to manually make sure those are in place further down the line.

Comment: A `BindClass` that contains `user` and `database` doesn't seem useful.

Comment: @developerwjk It could technically contain anything, just a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Your example design is perfectly fine, in fact it is a textbook example of how things should be done in the absence of specific information about what these classes are and what exactly they are supposed to do.

> My main concern is that I'm "including" something that already is
>   "connected" to Database.

Your main concern should instead be to make sure that each of the classes involved accurately and communicates its dependencies and its intended public interface to the outside world.

If a class such as `Database` really requires the services of some `User` in order to provide services to its own clients, then `Database` should take an instance of `UserInterface` (it's *much* better to use interfaces for this instead of concrete types) as a dependency, for example by requiring a constructor argument of that type.

Completely independently from the above, if it makes sense for `Database` to expose something like a `User` to its clients *in order to better fulfil its intended function* then by all means give it a public method that returns an instance of `UserInterface` (again, much better than a concrete type although in this case we are talking about phpdoc comments as the language cannot enforce restrictions based on the type of the return value). If the job of `Database` is not to provide a `User` to its clients then *it must not care* that it already has a `User` and that those clients might want to get one for their own purposes.

Note that you don't have two *instances* of a `User` here, just two *references* to the same instance -- there is no overhead. But if you wanted to for whatever reason (unit testing is a pretty common scenario) then you *could* have two instances, which would be impossible to do if you had `BindClass` pull the `User` out of `Database`.